# Gremlin Python project By clause

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, datastax-enterprise-graph, gremlinpython

Have a graph running on Datastax Enterprise Graph (5.1 Version), running on Cassandra storage.
Trying to run a query to get both the ID and the property.
In Gremlin Console I can do this:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).project("v", "properties").by().by(valueMap())
==>[v:v[1],properties:[name:[marko],age:[29]]]
```

How can I translate the valueMap call still using Python GraphTraversal API. I know I can run a direct query via Session Execution, like this.

```
session.execute_graph("g.V().has(\"Node_Name\",\"A\").project(\"v\", \"properties\").by().by(valueMap())",{"name":graph_name})
```

Below is my setup code.

```
from dse.cluster import Cluster, EXEC_PROFILE_GRAPH_DEFAULT
from dse_graph import DseGraph
from dse.cluster import GraphExecutionProfile, EXEC_PROFILE_GRAPH_SYSTEM_DEFAULT
from dse.graph import GraphOptions
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Order
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Column
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Direction
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Operator
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Pop
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Scope
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Barrier
graph_name = "TEST"
graph_ip = ["127.0.0.1"]
graph_port = 9042
schema = """
schema.edgeLabel("Group").create();
schema.propertyKey("Version").Text().create();
schema.edgeLabel("Group").properties("Version").add()
schema.vertexLabel("Example").create();
schema.edgeLabel("Group").connection("Example", "Example").add()
schema.propertyKey("Node_Name").Text().create();
schema.vertexLabel("Example").properties("Node_Name").add()
schema.vertexLabel("Example").index("exampleByName").secondary().by("Node_Name").add();
"""
profile = GraphExecutionProfile(
    graph_options=GraphOptions(graph_name=graph_name))
client = Cluster(
    contact_points=graph_ip, port=graph_port,
    execution_profiles={EXEC_PROFILE_GRAPH_DEFAULT: profile}
)
graph_name = graph_name
session = client.connect()
graph = DseGraph.traversal_source(session)

# force the schema to be clean
session.execute_graph(
    "system.graph(name).ifExists().drop();",
    {'name': graph_name},
    execution_profile=EXEC_PROFILE_GRAPH_SYSTEM_DEFAULT
)
session.execute_graph(
    "system.graph(name).ifNotExists().create();",
    {'name': graph_name},
    execution_profile=EXEC_PROFILE_GRAPH_SYSTEM_DEFAULT
)
session.execute_graph(schema)
session.shutdown()
session = client.connect()
graph = DseGraph.traversal_source(session)
```

Update:

I guess i have not made the problem clear. It is in python and not in gremlin console. So running code like `graph.V().has("Node_Name","A").project("v","properties").by().by(valueMap()).toList()` 
will give following result. How to execute the gremlin query while still remain in the GLV level, not drop down to text serialized query to Gremlin-Server?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph_test.py", line 79, in <module>
    graph.V().has("Node_Name","A").project("v", "properties").by().by(valueMap()).toList()
NameError: name 'valueMap' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not fully understand your question but it seems like you largely have the answer most of the way there. This last line of code:

```
graph = DseGraph.traversal_source(session)
```

should probably be written as:

```
g = DseGraph.traversal_source(session)
```

The return value of `traversal_source(session)` is a `TraversalSource` and not a `Graph` instance and by convention TinkerPop tends to refer to such a variable as `g`. Once you have a `TraversalSource`, then you can just write your Gremlin.

```
g = DseGraph.traversal_source(session)
g.V().has("Node_Name","A").project("v", "properties").by().by(valueMap()).toList()
```

Comment: i guess i have not made my question clear. It is in Python and I can not directly put valueMap in a by() clause as in regular Gremlin-Console.

Comment: this link should help: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_static_enums_and_methods

Comment: what makes you say that?

Comment: because "by(valueMap())" is not valid python code. And haven't found much documentations / example with Gremlin in python. Most are Gremlin in Groovy syntax.

Comment: Well, in case you are interested, a design decision was made to prefer that Gremlin code appear as "Gremlin" across all language variants. In this way, Gremlin would generally always look the same whether you used Java or Python or C# or whatever. That isn't always possible, but where it is possible TinkerPop bends the rules of what might be idiomatic for the language. In the case of python this means method naming like `valueMap()` instead of `value_map()`.

Comment: The positive side to this approach is that you don' need specific Python documentation to learn Gremlin. The java documentation provides the step descriptions and in many cases that code can be copy/pasted directly to python. You just need to be aware of the exception in Python to where that is not true.

Comment: I am not referring to the design decision, nor is the valueMap vs value_map. I could not find documentation on what is the valueMap equivalent in Python library, and still don't which package i should import so I can call valueMap/value_map.

Comment: sorry - maybe i'm not understanding the problem you're having. `valueMap()` from java is just `valueMap()` in python. The context you are using `valueMap()` in is the same for java as python and that context is from an anonymous traversal. Anonymous traversals are spawned in both java and python from the `__` class (double underscore). You can find that class here -  https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/6a663fe2ed52d1d321230f642bc9f516f0076ea9/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/process/graph_traversal.py#L509

Comment: The link I provided earlier to the reference documentation for python explains how to avoid use of the `__` class so that you can just call `valueMap()` instead of `__.valueMap()`. It showed how `statics.load_statics(globals())` to accomplish this. It even provides an example using `out()` step as the final example of the section. Does that help clarify things now. Does that help clarify things for you?